# Is it possible to customize an HTML <input required> attribute error message?

Tags: html, validation, required

I am using the HTML `required` attribute to perform in-page validation.

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Please see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Swy4hFEewCYlnL0bJKq1?p=streamer

But I don't want to show the default error text, "Please fill out this field.", instead I want another customized message say "You cannot leave the xyz field empty. Blah, blah, blah"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

HTML

```
<form action="">
    <input id="email" type="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
(function (exports) {
    function valOrFunction(val, ctx, args) {
        if (typeof val == "function") {
            return val.apply(ctx, args);
        } else {
            return val;
        }
    }

    function InvalidInputHelper(input, options) {
        input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.defaultText, window, [input]));

        function changeOrInput() {
            if (input.value == "") {
                input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.emptyText, window, [input]));
            } else {
                input.setCustomValidity("");
            }
        }

        function invalid() {
            if (input.value == "") {
                input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.emptyText, window, [input]));
            } else {
               console.log("INVALID!"); input.setCustomValidity(valOrFunction(options.invalidText, window, [input]));
            }
        }

        input.addEventListener("change", changeOrInput);
        input.addEventListener("input", changeOrInput);
        input.addEventListener("invalid", invalid);
    }
    exports.InvalidInputHelper = InvalidInputHelper;
})(window);



InvalidInputHelper(document.getElementById("email"), {
    defaultText: "Please enter an email address!",
    emptyText: "Please enter an email address!",
    invalidText: function (input) {
        return 'The email address "' + input.value + '" is invalid!';
    }
});
```

A working JSFiddle can be found at
http://jsfiddle.net/meghanagpal/B4hYG/622/

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, with a dash of JavaScript. You can use [`HTMLInputElement.setCustomValidity(String)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). When it's set to any non-empty string, the owning `<input>` won't validate.  You can call this within a `change` event or similar; if you decide, via your own code, that the `<input>` is invalid, just set the message. If you decide that it's all good, then set it to `""` (the empty `String`).